# Error while processing xml file

Tags: java, xml, doctype, stringbuilder

My requirement is to process xml file to search for character and replace it.
I am using following code for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File("C:/Users/demo.xml");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xmlFile));
           String line = null;
          while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
            if(line.indexOf("&") != -1)
            {
                line = line.replaceAll("&","&amp;");
            }
                sb.append(line);
          }
               br.close();

                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile));

                Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(sb.toString()));
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);


                bw.write(xmlOutput.getWriter().toString());
                bw.close();
                System.out.println("success");

           }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

When my xml file is :

```
<INFO>
<NAME>Joseph</NAME>
<BUSINESSNAME>M & A</BUSINESSNAME>
<INFO>
```

it is giving proper output
but with the following format (actual xml)

```
<!DOCTYPE CASE SYSTEM "C:\Program Files\abc.dtd">
<INFO>
<NAME>Joseph</NAME>
<BUSINESSNAME>M & A</BUSINESSNAME>
<INFO>
```

I am getting error: Error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\abc.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified).

Any solution?

Comment: Add the file to the path or change it accordingly?

Comment: Got it, doctype path and source file path must be same ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created this class to read strings from a xml file saved in internal storage device, it returns a list , if you want the whole extended string you only need concatenate to link together, if doesn't found the file return an empty list this is all you need to read XML files and parse to Strings, you can play with the list to replace letters in Strings,I hope to help!

```
public class readXMLFile {
private String filePath = "FileStorage";
private String fileName = "File.xml";
private final String tag = "Internal Read Persistence";
File internalFileData;

public readXMLFile() {// default constructor
}

public File getXMLFile(Context context){
File directory = null;
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
directory = cw.getDir(filePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
internalFileData = new File(directory, fileName);
if(internalFileData.exists()){
Log.i("ReadXMLFile","File returned");
return internalFileData;
}
else{
Log.i(tag,"the file doesn't exists!");
return null;
}
}

public List<String> readFile(Context context) {
List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
try {
File directory = null;
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
directory = cw.getDir(filePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
internalFileData = new File(directory, fileName);

if (internalFileData.exists()) {
Log.i("Internal Data", "the root exists!!");
try {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(internalFileData);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
l.add(line);
}
try {
if (in != null) {
in.close();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.i(tag, "Exception closing persistence connection");
            }
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.wtf("Fatal Exception", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
} else {
Log.i(tag, "File doesn't exists");
return l;//return empty list
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.wtf(tag, "Exception DATA READING: " + e.getMessage());
return l;
}
Log.i(tag, "file found return");
return l;
}

}
```